How to return a parameterized code block in PowerShell
Can a PowerShell function return a parameterized function as one would in JavaScript (see below)?
I would like to make a reusable code block which renames files in a case-sensitive way. This should not be a function but a code block which I can pass to ForEach-Object:
$Renamer = {
  Rename-Item $_ $_.name.replace("a", "A", $false, $null);
}
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object $Renamer

This works fine but now I want a function which returns the same code block but with different parameters.
function MakeRenamer($from, $to) {
  # This doesn't work, $from and $to are undefined
  return {
    Rename-Item $_ $_.name.replace($from, $to, $false, $null);
  }
}
$Renamer = MakeRenamer "a" "A"
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object $Renamer
$Renamer = MakeRenamer "b" "B"
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object $Renamer

This fails implying $from is null/undefined and thus is not being passed through.

JavaScript Example
function makeRenamer($from, $to) {
  return function(file) {
    file.name = file.name.replace(from, to);
  }
}
let renamerA = makeRenamer("a", "A");
let renamerB = makeRenamer("b", "B");

let myFile = {name:"aaab.txt"};
console.log(myFile.name); // "aaab.txt

renamerA(myFile);
console.log(myFile.name); // "AAAb.txt

renamerB(myFile);
console.log(myFile.name); // "AAAB.txt


The two examples are pretty different.  The powershell one doesn't take a file parameter, and you expect it to take pipeline input.

Not sure what you mean - the PowerShell code block I return is indeed run and receives the files I pipe to it via $_. The problem is that it didn't receive $from or $to but that is now solved.

PowerShell supports closures, which is what you're implicitly relying on in javascript - but in PowerShell you need to explicitly request it by calling GetNewClosure:
function New-Renamer {
    param (
        [string]$From,
        [string]$To
    )

    return {
        $_ |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace($from, $to, $false, $null)}
    }.GetNewClosure()
}

$renamer = New-Renamer -From a -To A

Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt |ForEach-Object $renamer



Mathias' helpful answer solves your problem exactly as asked, and explains the solution well (and is therefore the perfect choice for being the accepted answer).
Let me complement it with a streamlined alternative that obviates the need for a ForEach-Object call and relies on the automatic $input variable and direct invocation of the closed-over script block with &, the call operator:
function New-Renamer {
  param (
      $from,
      $to
  )

  return {
      # Use $input to refer to the pipeline input.
      # Note that .Replace() is case-sensitive and culture-sensitive *by default*.
      # -WhatIf is used to *preview* the renaming operation.
      $input | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace($from, $to) } -WhatIf
  }.GetNewClosure()
}

# Create a closed-over script block that captures the $from and $two arguments
# being passed.
$renamer = New-Renamer a A

# Invoke it directly in the pipeline, using &
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | & $renamer

Note: The -WhatIf common parameter in the command above previews the operation. Remove -WhatIf and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.
